# ¿Cómo poner un subtitulo debajo del titulo?

Tags: html, css

Quizás les parezca algo demasiado básico o estúpido, pero llevo varias horas dándole vueltas y no logro hacerlo, si alguien me hecha una mano, bienvenido sea. Gracias de antemano!

```css
header{
 align-items    : center;
 background     : red;
 display        : flex;
 height         : 25vh;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align     : center;
 width          : 100%;
}

.logo{
 -moz-border-radius   :100px;
 -webkit-border-radius:100px;
 background           : purple;
 border-radius        :100px;
 height               : 20vh;
 width                : 30vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.titulo{ 
   font-size: 5vh;
}

.sub-titulo{
   font-size: 3vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 
 <header>
  <div class="logo">
   <div class="titulo">TITULO</div>
   <div class="sub-titulo">SUBTITULO</div>
  </div>   
 </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Lo que pretendo es poner el div, "subtitulo" debajo del "Titulo" y a la vez, que estos permanezcan centrados en "logo"

Comment: ¿Si quieres uno debajo de otro porque estás usando flex? Puedes hacerlo con `flex-direction:column` pero es complicarse demasiado ya que los `div` por defecto son elementos de bloque y se ponen uno debajo de otro y simplemente añadiendo un `text-align:center` centras el texto

Comment: Lo haría así: `<h1 class="logo>TITULO<br><small>SUBTITULO</small></h1>` y en el CSS: `.logo{text-align:center;}`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes darle un [display contents](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) a dichos elementos.

```css
header{
 align-items    : center;
 background     : red;
 display        : flex;
 height         : 25vh;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align     : center;
 width          : 100%;
}

.logo{
 -moz-border-radius   :100px;
 -webkit-border-radius:100px;
 background           : purple;
 border-radius        :100px;
 height               : 20vh;
 width                : 30vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.titulo{ 
   font-size: 5vh;
}

.sub-titulo{
   font-size: 3vh;
}

.titulo, .sub-titulo {
display:contents;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 
 <header>
  <div class="logo">
   <div class="titulo">TITULO</div>
   <div class="sub-titulo">SUBTITULO</div>
  </div>   
 </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.logo-content{
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column; /* los pondrá en columna, ubicando el texto debajo del otro*/
justify-content: center; /* ubica los texto en la mitad del cuadro */
align-items: center; /* los ubica en el centro del cuadro */
background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Solid_pink.svg/1024px-Solid_pink.svg.png'); /* Le pongo un background image, esto para no escribir tanto codigo y sea más sencillo */
}
```

```html
<div class='logo-content'>
<h1>Color rosado</h1>
<p>Un color bonito que al principio era color estrella del hombre</p>

<p>de aquí para abajo puedes ir escribiendo subtitulos, todos se irán ubicando debajo del otro</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Lo que deseas hacer algo parecido a lo de la imagen]

```css
        .custom-logo-link {
            display: inline-block; 
            padding-right: 1em; 
            vertical-align: middle; 
            width: auto;
            }
        .wrap {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            max-width: 700px;
            padding-left: 2em;
            padding-right: 2em;
        }

        .site-title {
            clear: none;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            font-weight: 800;
            line-height: 1.25;
            letter-spacing: 0.08em;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .site-description {
            color: #666;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-size: 0.8125rem;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .site-branding-text {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUWfkfMunKQQEDIA1mH316Q" class="custom-logo-link"
               rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="250" height="250"
                src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AAuE7mAGZ7RLFX-KfBSUqU2sqa8xW6MPVHZnwIvwyg=s288-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no" 
                class="custom-logo" alt="Luly limon" itemprop="logo" 
                sizes="(max-width: 767px) 89vw, (max-width: 1000px) 54vw, (max-width: 1071px) 543px, 580px"></a>
                <div class="site-branding-text">
                        <h1 class="site-title"><a rel="home">Luly 
                         limon</a</h1>
                         <p class="site-description">Juegos y Diversión</p>
                     </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Si lo que que deseas como la imagen de arriba un logo con su texto centrado esto se puede lograr:

- Conteniendo todo el código en un div en este tiene clase wrap dentro de ello el logo como enlace ya que el logo se utiliza para llevarte a la página de inicio dando click en el.
- Dentro de clase wrap pondrias tambien el titulo con H1(en este caso es luly Limon) y el subtitulo con un p(en este caso juego y diversion).
- De ahi los css de wrap te serviran al menos los tres primero( margin-left, margin-right,max-width) para centrar todo el div.
- Para formatear el titulo usarías el css de site-title.
- Para formatear el subtitulo usarías el css de site-description
- y para que el logo y el texto quede centrado pues usarías los css de la clases  site-branding-text y .custom-logo-lin.

Con eso lograrias el efecto que aparece al ejecutar el código, suerte espero te ayude :)

Comment: Hola Arles. Normalmente se explica que hace tu código. Esta bien que le pongas todo el código necesario, pero dile, al menos por encima, que hace cada cosa y donde está el título.

Comment: Hola Arles, como te comenta @Emerita, puedes mejorar tu respuesta dando una breve explicación de cómo funciona el código, porqué hacerlo así y de qué manera esto soluciona el problema. Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Con `display:inline-block;` en la clase `logo`

Así colocaras un Div debajo del otro ^^

```css
header{
    align-items    : center;
    background     : red;
    display        : flex;
    height         : 25vh;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align     : center;
    width          : 100%;
}

.logo{
    -moz-border-radius   :100px;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px;
    background           : purple;
    border-radius        :100px;
    height               : 20vh;
    width                : 30vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  display:inline-block;
}

.titulo{    
   font-size: 5vh;
}

.sub-titulo{
   font-size: 3vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="titulo">TITULO</div>
            <div class="sub-titulo">SUBTITULO</div>
        </div>          
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías haber incluido todo el código relevante para una respuesta más clara.